# PHP Mailer script not completing after ajax call and form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to call a php script after a form submit using AJAX. The PHP script is called but nothing happens beyond that, no email received, no Error messages, etc. BUT it will redirect to homepage if php file is directly accessed through URL and the success property does perform the form reset properly.  TIA!

HTML:

```
<form id="form-box">
        <img id="form-logo" src="images/framework/logo.png">
        <p>
            <input name="first-name" id="first-name" type="text" maxlength="32" placeholder="First Name">
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label></p>
        <p>
            <input name="last-name" id="last-name" type="text" maxlength="32" placeholder="Last Name">
            <label for="last-name">Last Name</label></p>
        <p>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail">
            <label for="email">E-Mail</label></p>
        <p>
            <textarea name="comment-feedback" id="comment"></textarea></p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("#submit").on('click', function(){
        var fileName = document.location.pathname.match(/[^/]+$/),
            firstName = $('#first-name').val(),
            lastName = $('#last-name').val(),
            emailVal = $('#email').val(),
            comments = $('#comment').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../script/mail.php',
            data: {fname:firstName, lname:lastName, email:emailVal, comment:comments, fileName:fileName},
            success: function(){
                $('form').each(function() {
                    this.reset();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP: *Edit: Removed Validation for testing purposes, This did not work still.

```
<?php
$webmaster_email = "feedback@myDomain.com";
$index = "http://mydomain.com";
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comment'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

echo "$email_address";
echo "$comments";
echo "$fname";
echo "$lname";

/*function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
        '(\r+)',
        '(\t+)',
        '(%0A+)',
        '(%0D+)',
        '(%08+)',
        '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}*/

if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    header("Location: $index");
    exit;
}


elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments) || empty($fname)) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Please fill in the required fields.');</script>";
    exit;
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif (isInjected($email_address)){
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Please, Try Again.')";
    exit;
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
    mail("$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results", $comments, "From: $email_address");
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Thank You for contacting us!')";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are submitting the form AND performing an AJAX call. You have to prevent your form from posting, and only use the AJAX call.

Comment: Nope, it's just a button <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: your form is submitting check in console ajax response is success and display your submitted records.

Comment: I already made a fiddle with the OP code and the ajax call is succesfull....i think the problem is within the php code...just for testing, get rid off all the validation code

Comment: I removed the validation code and it did not change anything.  Is there any permissions I need to change for the file on my server?